# Issue with loading glyphicons using CSS font-face rule in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Note: Font Awesome is also being used

I'm using the glyphicon set in the branding of the website on the top left of the navigation bar - The text that reads "Best Castles in Town". The issue seems to be that the that the web font for glyphicons is not loading in. Instead a small square is visible where a tower icon should be in it's place. The tower icon should be rendered with the following markup which is present on the page:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>
```

http://www.bestcastlesintown.co.uk/prototype/test3.php#.UneSnRDylCj

I believe the CSS in stylesheet.css is correct for glyphicons usage:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}


.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Can anyone help resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>
```

This is the right way to insert glyphicons with bootstrap **3.0.0** but you are using bootstrap **2.3.2**

[The right way in bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons) is :

```
<i class="icon-tower"></i>
```

And as stated by zessx, this icon is not available in bootstrap **2.3.2**.

Answer (score 1):

The `tower` glyphicon comes in the 1.8 Glyphicon version, and is not available in Bootstrap 2.3.2.

You can have a look [into the doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons) to see Bootstrap 2.3.2 available glyphes, and see there's no `tower` glyphicon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Download the **entire** Bootstrap 3 folder and replace the font files with your current ones. I found out that font files in customized downloads are corrupted for some reason.

http://getbootstrap.com/